# Creating clusters with K-means plus plus clustering algorithm based on connected distance

Tags: java, algorithm, machine-learning, k-means, shortest-path

I have a set of nodes (around 10K) which are connected to each other. I have to create small clusters(max 15 nodes).

I'm using connected distance to find the distance between two nodes(using Dijkstra shortest path algorithm) instead of geospatial distance.
Now the problem is that It is taking more than 1 hour to create small clusters using K-means plus plus algorithm. I know it is taking more time to find the shortest distance between two nodes. If I want to store all shortest path initially itself, it requires more memory(it is impossible).
Can anyone suggest how can I optimize this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get. In K-Means you have to set up a distance for two nodes (centroid and node itself) to know which cluster the node itself is assigned. Now. Dijkstra? Shortest path between what?

Comment: Using Dijkstra's I'm getting shortest path between centroid and node itself (from the connected graph).

Comment: is a 'real' centroid or you set the centroid itself to the nearest node from it?

Comment: It is a real centroid. By Kmeans Algorithm way, I'm getting the centroid

Comment: Maybe I'm getting wrong, but because everytime centroids change, you can't save initially shortest path distance, mainly because everytime it changes. And anyway, I'm wondering: all nodes that are "nearest" to centroid have distance 0?

Comment: No. Always distance > 0 between any two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run dykstras algorithm for every node in your graph. Dykstras algorithm takes O(n^2 * log n) time on a dense graph. Which results into O(n^3 * log n), which takes pretty much forever. You could do the Floyd-Warshall (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) algorithm to turn this into O(n^3) as preprocessing and then use this algorithm, which would still take pretty long. The positive thing about this is, that you can store the shortest paths memory efficient with O(n^2) memory used.

There is nothing better for the all-pair shortest path problem on dense graphs.